# What is $g(y)$ if $g(y)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(xy)}{x^3}$ for $y>0$ and $g(1)=1$ for a non-zero $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Suppose $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a non-zero function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(xy)}{x^3}=g(y)$ exists for all $y>0$. If $g(1)=1$, then what is the exact functional form of $g(y)$ for all $y>0$ ?

I am not really sure how to proceed here.

I have $\frac{f(x)}{x^3}\to 1$ as $x\to \infty$. If I assume $f$ is differentiable more than once and that $f',f''$ all tend to $\infty$ as $x\to \infty$, then possibly I can use L'Hopital's rule to say something like $f'''(x)\to 6$ as $x\to \infty$. Doing something similar for $g(y)$ gives me $g(y)=y^2$ for  $y>0$.

I must be missing something obvious. A hint would be enough.

Comment: Just change variables to find the limit of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT;

Let $xy=t$ and note that for $y>0$, $t\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. I get $g(y)=y^3$.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And well done!

Comment: Can't believe I missed this despite having started with this change of variables.